# Adding constraint in such a way that a view won't exceed it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have the following configuration in my view using ConstraintLayout:

[image]

I want that "Admin" view was always on the right side of username view, but when username is too large admin view should always be visible. How to achieve it?

Currently:

[image]

EDIT:

Current code

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp0"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.8">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            style="@style/Text.Black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp6"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp16"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="veryveryveryverylongvervrusername" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mail"
            style="@style/Text.Grey"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            tools:text="fjfdjdf"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp12" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            style="@style/Text.White"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp18"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp9"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp9"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/name"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp5"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp5"
            android:singleLine="true"
            tools:text="Admin"
            tools:background="@drawable/bg_text_round_corners_blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp12" />
```

Comment: Do you have any layout code for your current solution?

Comment: Can you give a little more information on what you tried so far like your current xml code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the responses. I tried all of the solutions, but they either pushed "Admin" text out of the visibility when "username" is too large or made "admin" textview be glued to the right side without accounting the "username" size.

I was able to solve my problem to some extend by adding this percentage constraint to the "username" textview:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.75"
```

So it behaves like this:
[image]
[image]

Comment: hi, have you really tried my answer? i tested it with your code. it should definitely glue admin to the right side and allow width of username to be maximum until start of admin textview

Comment: @levdev sorry, if I didn't formulate the requirement correctly in my original post, but I don't need "Admin" glued to the right, rather make it on the right side of "username", but not leaving the area as on the image above.

Answer (score 2):

First on Admin Textview (@id+id/status) you have to add

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

Then on Username Textview (@+id/name) you can try add the following lines,

```
app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/status"
```

which whould constrain the width to be max until admin TextView

**update** (since i didn't fully understand your constraints)

the only way I could figure out to get this work is to create another ConstraintLayout inside the one that's already there, like this:

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/status"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="12dp"
                tools:text="veryveryveryverylongvervrusername" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:singleLine="true"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/name"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="12dp"
                tools:text="Admin" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The important point is to set

```
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
```

for both the username TextView and and the inner ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the layout_witdh of your Admin textview to 0dp like this:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/name"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/settings_icon"
```

The name textview needs to have something like this:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/status"
```

Comment: The point is, the status textview needs to be constrained to the right settings icon so it doesn't get pushed out of the view.

Answer (score 0):

For the field with id `@+id/name`, add below line:

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/status"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and change it's layout_width to

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            style="@style/Text.White"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp18"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp9"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp9"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp5"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp5"
            android:singleLine="true"
            tools:text="Admin"
            tools:background="@drawable/bg_text_round_corners_blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp12" />
```

Answer (score 0):

@bvk256

You can achieve the behavior with the following xml code, maybe slight bit cleanup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="90dp"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/startIcon"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/firstEditText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/admin"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/startIcon"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="hello world to this long and very very very very long text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/admin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="Admin"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/endIcon"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/firstEditText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/secondEditText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/admin"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/startIcon"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firstEditText"
    tools:text="hello world to this long and very very very very long text" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/endIcon"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
    android:tint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

[image]